# render html strings in flask templates

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm building a  web page to show articles. 
In my database, I have to attributes, one of which is used to put Markdown code and the other to save HTML code converted from the Markdown code. I want to get the HTML and add it to my base HTML.
I use `Flask` framework and `SQLAlchemy` and the data is saved in `sqlite` database.
My model:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    body = db.Column(db.String)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.String)
    tag = db.Column(db.String)
    info = db.Column(db.String)
    body_markdown = db.Column(db.String)
```

and my view function:

```
def post(post_id):
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == post_id).first()
    return render_template('post.html',
                           post = post,)
```

Firstly, I tried:

```
<div class="post-body">
    {{post.body}}
</div>
```

It shows the whole string with HTML tag.
`post.body.decode("utf-8")` and `post.body.decode("ascii")` didn't work, either.
When I debug the program, I found that the database returns `u'string'`.
How can I get pure HTML code and apply it in my base HTML file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default Jinja2 (the template engine for Flask) assumes input inside of `{{ }}` is unsafe and will not allow js or html inside them. You can solve this by using the `safe` filter inside your template. This will tell Jinja2 that the content is safe to render as is, and not to escape the html/javascript.

```
{{ post.body | safe }}
```