# Connexion/Flask/Jinja render template string as is

Tags: flask, jinja2

I want to put an html in a string, NOT a file, like:

```
t = """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>foo</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{ script|safe }}
</body>
</html>

"""

script = ...
render_template_string(t, script=script)
```

However when I go to the actual webpage, I don't see an html page with a script, I see garbage:

`"\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title>foo</title>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n  \n<script\n    src=\"http://localhost:5006/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=ff639949-97c5-40b8-9cc2-28b78be802d1&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp\"\n    id=\"ff639949-97c5-40b8-9cc2-28b78be802d1\"\n    data-bokeh-model-id=\"\"\n    data-bokeh-doc-id=\"\"\n></script>\n</body>\n</html>"`

How do I fix this?

EDIT: even a very simple

```
t = '{{ script|safe }}'
```

does not work, I get, in the browser:

```
"\n<script\n    src=\"http://localhost:5006/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=07a43696-66af-4e54-a4e3-9a09ac242e38&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006/bkapp\"\n    id=\"07a43696-66af-4e54-a4e3-9a09ac242e38\"\n    data-bokeh-model-id=\"\"\n    data-bokeh-doc-id=\"\"\n></script>"
```

EDIT 2: I have also tried

```
t = '{% autoescape false %}{{ script|safe }}{% endautoescape %}'
```

but that didn't work either.

I'm using Connexion if that matters.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215981/1377323?

Comment: Please post your view function.